# How best to maximize the initial 15,000 coins?

Tags: tap-my-katamari

Near the beginning of the game, the King bestows 15,000 coins. In terms of the return, is it a better investment to:

1. Invest it in the Prince's levels directly
2. Buy a cousin (and which one?)
3. Or some combination whereof?

Comment: Doing some research to put together a good answer.. are you sure the King bestows 15,000 coins? It was 20,000, for me, but it was through giving a free mushroom, so I do not think it was random.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>**Disclaimer:** In double checking my information, I played through the start of the game, again. I was given an initial 20,000 coins, as opposed to the 15,000 coins the asker was given. As this reward came in the form of a mushroom, I feel it is more likely that the average player will receive 20,000 coins, and have tailored my answer, accordingly. In my findings, the additional 5,000 coins are not enough to make a difference.</sup>

Starting up with Tap My Katamari can be quite confusing. The mechanics are complex, and there is little help given to the player. To add to the disadvantage, there is not much you can find online, in the way of help. Starting out, I was initially advised to *invest entirely on The Prince*, until a much higher level was reached. In cross checking my information with the game, after the experience of rolling a Level 1000 Prince, I found that **investing in Cousins can lead to much bigger returns, at the start**. If you do not include mechanics requiring you to leave the game idle for a brief period, investing directly in The Prince is the only real option.

To have a closer look, we need to look at how The Cousins actually work, in terms of mechanics and required investment. Unfortunately, the mechanics are quite complicated, for the lack of in-game help that is provided.

#### Building Cousin Power

The only initial benefit calling one of The Cousins will provide is a boost to Cousin Power. Cousin Power provides two benefits:

- The 'welcome back' bonus appears to be directly based off your Cousin Power.
- The strength of some Mojo abilities come from your current Cousin Power.

If you consider *not playing* as a suitable strategy to build your initial wealth, it might be a better option to focus on Cousin Power, at the start. In fact, it does not appear to take very long to 'refresh' the bonus. Just in leaving the game open, while I collected data and assembled this answer, I personally received the bonus twice. Very early, I received a bonus of 80,000 coins. With a Cousin Power of 5,570, I received my second bonus of 230,040 coins.

[image: A cousin bonus of 230,040, with the available option to double it.]

These bonuses make the initial 20,000 coins look like pocket change, and could easily go a lot further to level The Prince or The Cousins. Furthermore, you can click on the icon that says *Double* to watch an advertisement, and double the bonus you are receiving.

#### Activating Mojo

When you first activate any of The Cousins, they will appear on screen, and provide a bonus to your Cousin Power. That is all good and well, but as far as I have played, Cousin Power does not provide any standalone benefits during actual play. Rather, it is often the statistic that determines the power of Cousin abilities, referred to as Mojo.

Ultimately, Mojo will not activate until you have met the required Cousin level, and purchased the Mojo. That means **you will need to level your Cousin up to at least level 10, before you will gain real benefits from that Cousin. There is an additional cost to actually activate the Mojo**.

The abilities unlock at levels 10, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600 and 2000. When you get to the required level, you will still have to pay more coins to actually unlock the Mojo.

#### Initial requirements

At the start of the game, you only have access to four of The Cousins. Each of them have a certain amount of coins you would need to spend to unlock their Mojo.

The following lists each of these cousins, and the required investment to activate their Mojo, within the scope of 20,000 coins. In cases where I have included the level 50 Mojo, costs include the initial required upgrade to reach the level 10 Mojo.

- **Nik**: Level 10 Mojo: 703<sup>1</sup> coins; Level 50 Mojo: 20,323 coins.
- **Foomin**: Level 10 Mojo: 7,330 coins; Level 50 Mojo: over<sup>2</sup> 149,245 coins.
- **Lucha**: Level 10 Mojo: 21,000 coins.
- **Ace**: Level 10 Mojo: 65,930 coins.

[image: A cropped and stitched image showing the Call, Level 10 and Level 10 Mojo costs of the first three cousins.]

As you can see, 20,000 coins does not do much in unlocking Mojo. At best, you have three options, if you wish to pursue Mojo at the start.

- **Level 10 and 50 Mojo with Nik**: You could move towards unlocking the first two Mojo abilities with Nik. You fall short by 323 coins, but that is not a significant jump.
- **Level 10 Mojo with Lucha**: You could also move towards unlocking the first Mojo ability with Lucha. You fall short by 1,000 coins, but that is also arguably not a significant jump.
- **Level 10 Mojo with both Nik and Foomin**: With a total investment of 8,033 coins, you can unlock the first Mojo ability for two cousins. This *may* be the best option, with further investment in the Prince, but it really depends on other things. *See "Mojo Mechanics"*.

#### Mojo Mechanics

What makes the answer unique to each player is the fact that ***Mojo is completely random***. Your first Cousin may have a Level 10 Mojo that only increases Cousin Power, or a level 10 Mojo that greatly increases Click Power during challenges. There is also a power rating - Mojo will randomly be anything from a power level of 1 to a power level of 6. By clicking on the portrait of a Cousin, you can view that Cousins Mojo abilities. You can also click on the candy icon, to the right of each Moho ability, to re-roll the Mojo at a cost of 5 candies. If you wish to re-roll a Mojo, [it is worth considering the options](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271913/what-are-all-the-possible-mojo-powers). You can just as easily roll a less-beneficial Mojo, if you do not know what you are looking for.

This is where things get a bit more complicated. Given that you could very well have some level 6 Mojo that increases treasure or Click Power signficicantly, you may make the executive decision to favour Mojo with your initial investment. Given that the benefits mostly work as a percentage (for example, increasing Click Power by a *percentage* of your current Click Power), you may still only notice real benefits after further investment in upgrading the level of The Prince.

As you can see in the screenshot, below, I rolled a level 4 "Powerful" Mojo, increasing the Cousin Power of that specific Cousin by 350%. At the start, I have no other Mojo that benefits from Cousin Power, but this substantial increase goes well towards my 'welcome back' bonus.

[image: An example of the Mojo screen.]

<sub><sup>1</sup> During my tests, I accidentally upgraded Nik to level 2, before taking the final screenshot that went into the image. Despite the insignificant discrepancy this would cause, if comparing the numbers, I had luckily taken a screenshot of the level 2 upgrade, by mistake. As such, the upgrade costs are still accurate to the coin.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> During my tests, I did not progress enough to afford upgrading Foomin to level 50. Given that the cost already greatly exceeds the limitations of the scope, I feel it is unnecessary.</sub>

Comment: The more I looked into this, the more confusing it got. **Please comment with any confusion or discrepancy**, so I can update my answer, accordingly. I feel it would not be hard for me to miss something, the documentation for this game is really quite pathetic.