# What are all the possible Mojo powers?

Tags: tap-my-katamari

A major part to Tap My Katamari is the bonuses provided by having The Cousins. Bonuses are provided at varying levels, but are somewhat random, in both mechanic and strength.

On top of that, the player may spend candy to re-roll any of the abilities. With the greatly increasing cost to upgrade the level of a Cousin, it can sometimes be a better option to simply re-roll an unwanted ability.

That said, without knowing what possible upgrades or downgrades you may receive, it is hard to work out if it is actually worth rerolling a Mojo ability. Am I more likely or less likely to receive a Mojo ability more in line with my play style? If I roll a more powerful version of the same Mojo, how much of a benefit will I receive?

It is almost impossible to determine the answers without knowing what all the Mojo possibilities are.

**What are the possible Mojo abilities, and what are the varying strengths?**

Answer (score 2):

**Brave**: Increases Tap Power during challenges.

- Rank I: 8% increase.
- Rank II: 10% increase.
- Rank III: 14% increase.
- Rank IV: 20% increase.
- Rank V: 30% increase.
- Rank VI: 40% increase.

**Energetic**: Increases Tap Power by a percentage of overall Cousin Power.

- Rank I: 0.4% increase.
- Rank II: 0.5% increase
- Rank III: 0.7% increase.
- Rank IV: 1% increase.
- Rank V: 1.4% increase.
- Rank VI: 2% increase.

**Helpful**: Increases both Tap Power and overall Cousin Power.

- Rank I: 5% increase.
- Rank II: 7% increase.
- Rank III: 11% increase.
- Rank IV: 17% increase.
- Rank V: 25% increase.
- Rank VI: 35% increase.

**Lucky**: Increases the bonus Tap Power of critical hits.

- Rank I: 5% increase.
- Rank II: 7%increase.
- Rank III: 11% increase.
- Rank IV: 17% increase.
- Rank V: 25% increase.
- Rank VI: 35% increase.

**Magical**: Increases Tap Power.

- Rank I: 5% increase.
- Rank II: 7% increase.
- Rank III: 10% increase.
- Rank IV: 14% increase.
- Rank V: 19% increase.
- Rank VI: 25% increase.

**Powerful**: Increases that Cousin's Cousin Power.

- Rank I: 50% increase.
- Rank II: 100% increase.
- Rank III: 200% increase.
- Rank IV: 350% increase.
- Rank V: 550% increase.
- Rank VI: 800% increase.

**Regal**: Increases the coin collection from the King's Treasure bonus.

- Rank I: 10% increase.
- Rank II: 14% increase.
- Rank III: 19% increase.
- Rank IV: 25% increase.
- Rank V: 32% increase.
- Rank VI: 40% increase.

**Smart**: Increases the coin collection from objects.

- Rank I: 5% increase.
- Rank II: 7% increase.
- Rank III: 11% increase.
- Rank IV: 17% increase.
- Rank V: 25% increase.
- Rank VI: 35% increase.

**Sneaky**: Increases critical chance.

- Rank I: 0.2% increase.
- Rank II: 0.4% increase.
- Rank III: 0.8% increase.
- Rank IV: 1.1% increase.
- Rank V: 1.5% increase.
- Rank VI: 2% increase.